# UILocalNotification gets vanished when the phone lights gets dimmed in ObjC

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

> I am developing the alarm application by using UILocalNotification, at
>   the alarm time i am firing two local notifications continuously.
>
> But when first notification finishes at the time second notifications
>   comes but as soon as screen light gets dimmed the notification
>   immediately vanishes.
>
> This works fine when phone is locked!

Can i get any workaround for this scenario?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have code that dismisses the notifications? If so, have you placed a breakpoint in that code to make sure it's not getting called for some reason?

Comment: i looked, but no such breakpoint there!

Comment: Do you have code that dismisses the alerts?

Comment: No such code, i have checked this happens only when notification came and screen light gets dimmed but when phone is locked it working fine

Comment: I searched lot, that the default behaviour of iOS.